# Leaflet image mask

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, maps, mask

Is there a way of displaying images with a geoJson mask in Leaflet/another map library? I took "choropleth map of US States" example and I'd like to display a different background image in each state. How can I achieve it?

Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/d37zg8f9/, as you can see the images overflow from each state. In a perfect world something like that can be achieved by following HTML:

```
<svg>
    <mask id="mask">
        <path d=".."></path>
    </mask>
    <image mask="url(#mask)" href=".."></image>
</svg>
```

But I'm not sure if there's a way of injecting that into Leaflet.

Comment: You can use libraries like https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern which applies the image directly to the path and not over an `L.ImageOverlay`

Comment: @FalkeDesign do you mind providing any example with a real image? Can't see anything like that in their documentation

Comment: I forgot to write, that you need to adjust the code. I know it is possible but sadly I can't share the code with you because of my company guidelines

Comment: Got it, thanks anyway! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*https://jsfiddle.net/9rzt2uoe/29*

**You can use the `fill` property in CSS to fill SVG paths with SVG patterns.**

We need an SVG to hold a bunch of patterns that each contain an image:

```
<body>

   <div id='map'></div>

   <svg id='patterns' width="0" height="0">
      <defs id='defs'>
      </defs>
   </svg>

</body>
```

In `onEachFeature`, instead of adding image overlays on the map, images are added as patterns in `defs` in the `patterns` SVG:

```
let i = 300;

const svgPatternsDefs = document.getElementById('defs');

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
   const imageUrl = `https://picsum.photos/${i++}`;
   const imageBounds = layer.getBounds();
   const imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds);
   //imageOverlay.addTo(map);
   const imageId = `picture-${i}`;
   defs.innerHTML += `
      <pattern id='${imageId}' width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
         <image xlink:href='${imageUrl}' width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
      </pattern>
   `;
   Promise.resolve().then(() => { // defers execution
      layer.getElement().style.fill = `url(#${imageId})`;
   });
}
```

`layer.getElement()` returns `undefined` until the layers get added to the map. Code execution can be deferred with `Promise.resolve().then`

```
const geoJson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
   onEachFeature,
   style : {
      "fillOpacity" : 1
   }
}).addTo(map);
```

`fillOpacity` is 0.2 by default and should be set to 1 for images to be shown correctly.

Comment: crafted a similar solution yesterday, thanks for the help!